# Django. Несколько инстансов

Tags: django, сервер, docker, uwsgi

Есть проект написанный на Django/Python, крутится под uwsgi+nginx.

Появились желающие получить абсолютно идентичный функционал для своего проекта. Как правильней организовать деплой и хранение нескольких инстансов проекта в рамках 1 сервера. Будет ли корректно использовать для этого Docker?

Так же планируется определенный фронтэнд для управления инстансами - удаление, создание и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Просто поднять рядом еще один процесс uWSGI и настроить в nginx дполнительныц virtualhost.

Comment: Так это и работает для остальных сайтов (uwsgi правда с васалами).

Comment: Тут другая ситуация, подразумевается определенное управление инстансами и их автоматическая установка/удаление/клонирование

Comment: Операция настолько элементарна, что достаточно шелл-скрипта.

Comment: Потом так же писать еще с десяток шел скриптов для копирования, удаления инстанса из веба?